# Instruct geometer moths so you can learn about their true geometry.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry

I had a space-ship wreck in an unknown world of some kind of moths.  I could observe geometer moths working. Everything looked strange. The moths claimed that they were using only straight edges and compasses. I asked them to construct a tangent lines to a circle $c$ from a point $P$. (So, thought I, I could learn more about their geometry.)

I include the final result I was allowed to take a photo of:

[image]

Now, this is what they did:

1. They drew a white circle $c'$ through $P$ around $C$.
2. They joined $C$ and $P$ with a segment
3. They chose a point $X$ on $c$.
4. They erected a perpendicular to $XC$ at $X$.
5. This perpendicular intersected $c'$ at $X'$
6. They copied the angle $\alpha=\angle XX'C$ over $CP$ at $C$.
7. The red line was apparently a tangent to $c$.

Then they ridiculed me for I could not tell which geometry was their natural one.

Could you order them to construct the tangent so that you be able to tell if they were hyperbolic moths, spherical moths, or Euclidean moths?

I asked the geometer moth's to find a tangent line to another circle from another point $P$.

[image]

In this case I instructed them as follows.

1. Connect $C$ and $P$ with a segment.
2. Halve the segment. The middle point was denoted by $H$.
3. Construct a circle centered at $H$ through $P$.
4. Connect one of the intersection points of  the two circles ($c$, $c'$) with $P$.
5. We did not get a tangent line.

The geometer moths confessed that their geometry was not Euclidean. But they did not want to tell if it was hyperbolic or elliptic.

Help needed to make up a method of constructing the tangent line so that one can separate the two remaining geometries.

[Don't question the existence of geometer moth's!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometer_moth)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking for (a) determining their geometry from the given procedure, (b) a procedure for determining a tangent that enables one to distinguish between the model geometries, or (c) something else?

Comment: @Neal: I am sorry if my question is not clear. Yes, I am asking all your questions: (a) Is it possible to make a decision about their geometry given the construction described? (b) I am asking for such a procedure to determine the tangent such that at the end the observer will get closer to the nature of the geometry. (c) Something else: There are three geometries mentioned: hyp, Eu, and Sph. Is it possible to suggest a tangent finding procedure that will make it possible to single out one of the geometries mentioned?

Comment: I can describe a procedure that only works in Euclidean geometry. Would that help?

Comment: @Blue: I know the method that works only in Euclidean geometry. What I don't know is how to separate the hyperbolic and the elliptic geometry. The method I gave in the OP does not separate these two geometries.

Comment: @zoli: You should be a little clearer in your question. I suggest that you provide "the method that only works in Euclidean geometry" (although, presumably, there are actually many of these) so that we don't duplicate your thought processes; and then ask specifically for methods that distinguish the hyperbolic and spherical cases.

Comment: @Blue: I edit accordingly. (Give me five minutes, please.)

Comment: @Blue: I've edited my post.

Comment: Suppose your Euclidean tangent test fails as described, with (non-tangent point) $T$ the intersection of the two circles; and let $S$ be the other point of intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{PT}$ and $\bigcirc C$. Can we tell which non-Euclidean geometry we're in by whether $S$ lies *inside* or *outside* $\bigcirc H$?

Comment: @zoli: I believe the answer to my question (about $S$ and $\bigcirc H$) is *yes*. It'll take some time to write-up a proof, so let me know whether this type of solution would be satisfactory.

Comment: The construction described in the question, by the way, uses that the space is symmetric, so it cannot distinguish between the model geometries.

Comment: @zoli It would work to measure angle deviation in the triangle constructed in method one, but that doesn't quite seem in the spirit of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier when you ask them to make a square.

Starting with 3 right angles (they are constructable ) what is the measure of the fourth angle? if it is larger than a right angle their geometry is spherical , if it is smaller than a right angle it is hyperbolic

Having a look at your second construction you did get a line that cut the circle in two places.

The other point where it cut the circle was that between T and P? if so it is hyperbolic.

If T is between P and the second point it is spherical.
the proof sketch is a bit:

Draw the lines PT and PT'  that are  the tangent line to circle c going trough P

In spherical geometry the lines PT, PT' and PC are will eventually meet at the anti pole of P

all lines that intersect circle c between T and T' will have to cut the circle twice . (because they all go trough the antipole of P

All what then remains is to prove that the intersections of circles c and c' are between T and T'

and this can be proven by proving that HT is larger than HC

(and I haven't solved this bit yet)

PS No it is not easier to make a triangle , you get in a mess with very big triangles or very messy measurements, it is much simpler to try squares.

Comment: Your suggestion works. However, it would be easier to construct a triangle. The real problem is that I am looking for a tangent line construction that could test the actual geometry. But, please explain further if you 3 right angle + a 4th one is a tangent construction,

Comment: Yes, the second construction was hyperbolic. Now, can you tell where the "second point" have to be if the geometry is spherical?

Comment: Could you detail this proposal as an answer?! One of my problems is, is that I could not even prove that the second construction does not work in spherical geometry.

Comment: After long thinking the answer is quite easy

in spherical geometry the lines PT and PC are will eventually meet at the anti pole of P 

the maximum distance at between the two lines at C must be at an right angle so draw the perpendicular to PC through C , let where it cuts PT be H. now prove is that T is between H and P (triangle inequality) and that H is inside circle c (sinus rule) and you are done.

Comment: added start of a proof (not complete yet)